# Converting SLD to MapboxGL style

Tags: mapbox, sld, mapbox-gl-js

I'm struggling to convert SLD (from Qgis) to MapboxGL style format.
Does anyone have any ideas if this is possible?

Comment: Use the plugin qgis2web to transform seamlessly your entire project to Mapbox GL (including styles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used qml to convert Corine vector data style to mapbox style. Qml style doesn't work for raster style.

npx geostyler -t mapbox -o corine_AllClass.mapbox - s  qml corine_AllClass.qml

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/terrestris/geostyler/blob/master/README.md
GeoStyler will do this and other conversions

Comment: I am using rule based symbology method for Corine data. Geostyler gave a result without color info. qgis2web can't handle this type of symbology and give me just base map. Not only for mapbox, also for leaflet and openlayers option didn't work

https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/866

Comment: I was also not getting the colors, till I replaced <SvpParameter> to <CssParameter>

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before. Geostyler can do thejob

Here is the repository: https://github.com/geostyler/geostyler-cli

and how to use it

`npm install -g geostyler-cli`

`geostyler -t mapbox -o output.json input.sld`

you can optionally use the option `-s se` for SLD 1.0 or `-s sld` SLD 1.1